# How to make foreign key unsigned in Django

Tags: django

I want to know how to make foreign key unsigned in Django v1.11.

I have two tables: `tournament` and `vip_promotion`.

The `id` primary key in `vip_promotion` is `int`, `unsigned`.
When I created a migration for `tournament` table, I couldn't make a foreign key to `vip_promotion`, because Django only makes foreign key column is only  `int` without `unsigned`.

Is there any way to make foreign key column is `unsigned` in Django?

```
class Tournament(BrickModel):
  display_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  vip_promotion = models.ForeignKey(Vip_Promotion, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: unsigned means you want to make pkey as allowed -1,-2,-3..?

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari
Did you miss something? Because `UNSIGNED` only stores positive numbers.

Comment: am I right or not?

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari

All integer types can have an optional (nonstandard) attribute UNSIGNED. Unsigned type can be used to permit only nonnegative numbers in a column or when you need a larger upper numeric range for the column. For example, if an INT column is UNSIGNED, the size of the column's range is the same but its endpoints shift from -2147483648 and 2147483647 up to 0 and 4294967295.

You should check here first to understand an unsigned type https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Comment: But you haven't explained why you want this.

Comment: in Vip_Promotion have you tried pk= models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)

Comment: @JibinMathews I can't do this, because the `Vip_Promotion` table already exists. I can't make any change to this table

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to make the column in `Tournament` table is the same type as a primary key in `Vip_Promotion` table. So I can link for foreign key between them. If the column type is not same , you couldn't make the foreign key

Comment: Django will automatically do this when you create the migration for Tournament.

Comment: No, it didn't. Django only makes `integer` column type. it didn't make column  unsigned type

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. Either the Vip_Promotion table has a positive integer field as its primary key - in which case it should be represented as such in the Django model, and Django will then do the right thing when creating foreign keys to it - or it doesn't, in which case you don't need this.

Comment: The Vip_Promotion table already exists and it was made manually not by migration file. Django can create column but it doesn't make the column is unsigned type so foreign key and index are not created in Tournament table.

Comment: Sigh. If it was made manually, then you must have manually told Django about your fields. So you should update the definition of the primary key field in Django to match what it actually it is in the database.

Answer (score 3):

you can write own custom model fields for this.

```
# MySQL unsigned integer (range 0 to 4294967295).
class UnsignedAutoField(models.AutoField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'integer UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT'

    def rel_db_type(self, connection):
        return 'integer UNSIGNED'
```

## Ref:- [Writing custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-model-fields/)

Comment: Thank you, this is a good idea. Does it create the index and foreign key when run migrate?

Comment: For reference:
```
class UnsignedBigIntegerForeignKey(models.ForeignKey):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL'

    def rel_db_type(self, connection):
        return 'bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL'
```